# How to get the angle between two vectors in pygame?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, angle

I want my player to look towards some certain coordinates in pygame. I tried to do this by getting the angle between the position of the player and the coordinates and then rotating it the player by that angle. I used a function for this ,the function works properly when I need my player to look towards the coordinates of the mouse , but fails when i use the same function to make a zombie look towards the player.
This was the function that is used.

```
def rotate_char(khiladi,vector,old_center,angle=False) :
x1, y1 = vector
x2, y2 = khiladi.pos
dx, dy = x2 - x1, y2 - y1

rads = atan2(dx, dy)
degs = degrees(rads)

r_khiladi = pygame.transform.rotate(khiladi.image, degs)

R_k = r_khiladi.get_rect()
R_k.center = old_center
screen.blit(r_khiladi, (R_k))
if angle : return degs
```

I used another method that used numpy

```
v1_u = list(khiladi.pos / linalg.norm(khiladi.pos))
v2_u = list(vector / linalg.norm(vector))
v1_u[1] , v2_u[1] = -v1_u[1] , -v2_u[1]
c_angle =  degrees(arccos(clip(dot(v1_u, v2_u), -1.0, 1.0)))
```

When I tried to print the angles they were totally off mark and didn't even showed any pattern.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) / [`angle_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to) to compute the angle between 2 vectors in degrees.

If *(x1, y1)* and *(x2, y2)* are 2 vectors, then the angle between the vectors is:

```py
v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1, y1)
v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2, y2)
angle_v1_v2_degree = v1.angle_to(v2)
```

---

In general The *dot* product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

This follows, that the *dot* product of 2 [unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors, because the length of a unit vector is 1.

```
uA = normalize( A )
uB = normalize( B )
cos( angle_A_B ) == dot( uA, uB )
```

[image: A dot B]

Hence the angle between 2 vectors can be computed by [`math.acos`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) of the [`dot`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.dot) product of the 2 normalized vectors ([normalize()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)):

```py
v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1, y1)
v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2, y2)
v1u_dot_v2u = v1.normalize().dot(v2.normalize())
angle_v1_v2_radian = math.acos(v1u_dot_v2u)
```

Comment: the problem still exists , should I show some more code to help ?

Comment: @TheInfo Please note _(x1, y1)_ and _(x2, y2)_ have to be vectors, not points). Is there some origin _(x0, y0)_? If yes, then the vectors are _(x1-x0, y1-y0)_ and _(x2-x0, y2-y0)_

Comment: in a pygame screen the origin or [0,0] is at top left corner of the screen and also note that in pygame y value increases as we go down . For ex i use pygame's inbuilt function to get mouse position and i pass the coordinates obtained to the rotate_char function.